# Transaction not successfully started

Tags: java, hibernate, derby

```
public void saveSoDtls(SoDtls soDtls){    
            try {
                 session = HibernateSessionFactory.getSessionFactory()
                        .openSession();

                session.beginTransaction();

                 session.save(soDtls);

                session.getTransaction().commit();

               //Creating pdf file (itext) using SoDtls object 
            } catch (HibernateException hex) {
                session.getTransaction().rollback(); 
                throw hex;
            }catch (Exception ex) {
                session.getTransaction().rollback();  //------> getting error at this line
                throw ex;
            }finally{
                if(session != null){
                    session.close();
                }
            }
}
```

1. I want to sync both commit and creating file. If there is any error while creating file then there should be rollback of the transaction.
2. If there is any error while committing transaction then file should not be created. (This scenario working fine)

But first scenario is not working fine as I am getting transaction not successfully started while rollbacking if there is error while creating pdf file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U cannot rollback committed transaction, maybe you should create file then commit transaction and if something bad happened just delete file and rollback

```
        try {

            session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(soDtls);
           //Creating pdf file (itext) using SoDtls object 

            session.getTransaction().commit();

        }}catch (Exception ex) {
            deleteFileIfExists();
            session.getTransaction().rollback();  //------> getting error at this line
            throw ex;
        }finally{
            if(session != null){
                session.close();
            }
        }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

you can try below sample code:

```
try {
  final Session session = HibernateSessionFactory.getSessionFactory()
                        .openSession();

  final Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

    // do things


    if (!tx.wasCommitted()) {    
      tx.commit();
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {
    tx.rollback();
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Comment: Transaction tx object  will not be accessible within the scope of catch block because you have created inside try block